# Deploy Visual studio class library project to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy an existing .NET project from visual studio to Azure. The project output type is listed as class library under properties-> Application on visual studio. The web tab under project properties has a start url and project url listed. I am not very familiar with Azure, Should this project be published as a app service, cloud service or anything else on Azure. The project uses a database which I have already created on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are either having web application project or web api project ( this does not have any UI layer and it is purely a service.)

So in the web application case you will be using the azure web app service and for the api/ webservice case you will use api apps.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/